# 2021 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Code Review's [third moderator election](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/election/3) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the two new moderators are:

[image: SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ] [image: Peilonrayz]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes! We'd also like to thank departing moderators Vogel612 and Mathieu Guindon for the time you've spent moderating the site.

Due to the remarkably close votes for the second slot and [community and moderator support](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10677/request-to-add-an-extra-moderator-given-the-2021-election-results), we've decided to add a third winner to this election:

[image: Mast]

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/election/3), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5607078484770816).

Comment: Thanks for everything you're doing Catija. Congratulations to the new moderators, and special mention to runner-up Mast for an incredibly close race!

Answer (score 28):

Congratulations to you both, I'm sure you'll make a fine addition to the team. I know the both of you to be very active and very experienced. The site is in good hands.

Comment: Oh wow… it was such a tight race for the second-place finisher. Better luck next time, I guess?

Comment: @200_success Currently [the closest known election](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/363798). Thanks Mast, if you're ever in need of hammers you know where to find me!

Comment: I picked you for the first position :) 
Congratulations.

Comment: Congratulations on the diamond! Naturally, I voted for you in the election, as I've been telling you for years now that you'd make a great moderator. I'm glad Catija finally listened to me. :-)

Answer (score 14):

Congratulations to the winners. I believe the site is in good hands.

Answer (score 5):

Belated **congratulations to @Sᴀᴍ Onᴇᴌᴀ, @Peilonrayz and @Mast** on winning the 2021 Code Review Stack Exchange election!

It's amazing to see how Sᴀᴍ Onᴇᴌᴀ and Peilonrayz both have pretty much [perfect candidate scores](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/election/3?tab=election#post-259591)!

And my respects to Mast for [being a such great sport](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10675/229550) at the time when they were [so close](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/363798) but didn't win. All in all they ended up with their diamond, and that's only fair as they've earned it!

*Wishing you all the best!*

Comment: Wow almost didn't see your post D: Thanks! :)